# how to split each word in a string in a seperate list

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

How would I go about splitting each word in a string in a separate string? if I, for example, have this code

```
s = "It sure is a nice day today"
l = list(s)
```

This would return `['I', 't', ' ', 's', 'u', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'd', 'a', 'y', ' ', 't', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'y']` instead, I's like to have it return seperate lists like so:

```
['I', 't']
['s', 'u', 'r', 'e']
['i', 's']
['a']
['n', 'i', 'c', 'e']
['d', 'a', 'y']
['t', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'y']
```

And if possible store them in seperate lists instead of simply printing them.

Comment: So you want a *list of lists*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well this looks like a *list of lists*, since you need some datastructure to store these sublist in.

For example:

```
s = "It sure is a nice day today"
result = [list(si) for si in s.split()]
```

This then generates:

```
>>> result = [list(si) for si in s.split()]
>>> result
[['I', 't'], ['s', 'u', 'r', 'e'], ['i', 's'], ['a'], ['n', 'i', 'c', 'e'], ['d', 'a', 'y'], ['t', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'y']]
```

Of course you can also store these sublists in a tuple, etc. But somehow you will have to wrap these into a collection that can store lists.

Answer (score 4):

A `map`-based version of otherwise impeccable @WillemVanOnsem's answer:

```
list(map(list, s.split()))
#[['I', 't'], ['s', 'u', 'r', 'e'], ['i', 's'], ['a'], ['n', 'i', 'c', 'e'], ['d', 'a', 'y'], ['t', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'y']]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to split a string, here's how I normally do it

```
   var S= "my name is sam",
   K= s.split (''),
   FirstLetter= k [0];
```

Comment: I think there are some problems with this answer: (a) the idea is to return lists of characters *split per word*, here you obtain the first character of the string; (b) this looks like JavaScript and not Python, since it uses a `var` keyword; and (c) one can obtain the first character with `s[0]` so no need to do this `split`ting.